# OCaml function application precedence and associativity

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc

I need to give high precedence and left associativity to function application in my OCaml parser. I have a bunch of different tokens it matches for such as

```
%token LET REC EQ IN FUN ARROW 
%token IF THEN ELSE
%token PLUS MINUS MUL DIV LT LE NE AND OR
%token LPAREN RPAREN
```

and I gave all of these precedence and associativity using `%left`,`right`... 
However, since `exp` that I'm using to match with isn't a token I was wondering how I would do that in this case:

```
exp:
| exp exp                    { App($1,$2)}
```

I have all my matches for `exp`, didnt make a bunch of different exp1 exp2s and so on and want to know if its possible to give `exp` `exp` the highest precedence and left assoc it.

I posted this on another forum for my class and got:

You can associate a dummy token with the function application rules as follows:

```
rule:   ....   %precc DUMMY_FUN_APP
```

And then specify associativity using %left and the dummy token.

But im not really sure what this means so if someone could elaborate on this or give me another solution that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what parser generator you're using. If you're using ocamlyacc, you might look at the actual grammar of OCaml for ideas. You can find the grammar here: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/parsing/parser.mly

In `parser.mly`, tokens are listed in precedence order from low to high. Some of the tokens are dummy tokens that are listed only to establish a precedence. These tokens are then referenced from within the syntax rules using `%prec token_name`.

Here are the last few lines of the token list:

```
%nonassoc below_SHARP
%nonassoc SHARP          /* simple_expr/toplevel_directive */
%nonassoc below_DOT
%nonassoc DOT
/* Finally, the first tokens of simple_expr are above everything else. */
%nonassoc BACKQUOTE BANG BEGIN CHAR FALSE FLOAT INT INT32 INT64
          LBRACE LBRACELESS LBRACKET LBRACKETBAR LIDENT LPAREN
          NEW NATIVEINT PREFIXOP STRING TRUE UIDENT
```

Note that the dummy token `below_SHARP` has very high precedence.

Here are the relevant rules for function application:

```
expr:
  | simple_expr simple_labeled_expr_list
      { mkexp(Pexp_apply($1, List.rev $2)) }

simple_labeled_expr_list:
    labeled_simple_expr
      { [$1] }
  | simple_labeled_expr_list labeled_simple_expr
      { $2 :: $1 }

labeled_simple_expr:
    simple_expr %prec below_SHARP
      { ("", $1) }
```

For what it's worth, I've always found `yacc` associativity and precedence delcarations to be extremely tricky to understand except in simple cases.

Comment: I ended up just using the version with multiple exprs, yes I was using yacc